# Call XRSystem.isSessionSupported return true, but Failed to execute 'requestSession' on 'XRSystem'

Tags: javascript, mobile, aframe, webxr

I'm trying to make a webXR application with A-Frame.
I want to detect whether user device(usally mobile) is support AR or not,
So I follow [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XRSystem/isSessionSupported) instruction.

```js
    navigator.xr.isSessionSupported("immersive-ar").then((allow) => {
      if (allow === false) {
        message.innerHTML = `AR not supported`;      
      }
    });

    if (navigator.xr === undefined) {
      message.innerHTML = `XR not supported`;
    }
```

The problem is that Even the paramter allow is return **true**, but when user touch the button at bottom right(Enter AR), It's throw an error of `Could not create a session because: The runtime for this configuration could not be installed`.

I can run my application on some mobile, but when the device not support, It will stuck.

Am I wrong? Is there another way to detect supported status?

```
navigator.xr.isSessionSupported("immersive-ar").then((allow) => {
      if (allow === false) {
        // Expect: When EnterAR(true) wont working, show this. 
        message.innerHTML = `AR not supported`;
      }
    });

    if (navigator.xr === undefined) {
       // Expect: When EnterAR(true) wont working, or show this.
      message.innerHTML = `XR not supported`;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [this issue](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4660). `a-frame` uses [`navigator.xr.supportsSession('immersive-ar')`](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/utils/device.js#L63) for support detection, but since you have the option to press the `AR` button, the browser is providing invalid info.

Since the detection can be faulty, You could

- get the device info with a library like [platform.js](https://github.com/bestiejs/platform.js)
- run it against the the [ARCore supported devices](https://developers.google.com/ar/devices) (there is a `.csv` available) and check if there is a match